# Siegel Levi in $\operatorname{GSpin}(2n+1)$ and image into $\operatorname{SO}(2n+1)$

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, langlands-conjectures, reductive-groups

Let $T$ be a maximal torus of split $\operatorname{SO}_{2n+1}$ with basis $e_1, ... , e_n$.  Let $$\Delta = \{e_1 - e_2, ... , e_{n-1} - e_n, e_n\}$$ be a set of simple roots of $T$ corresponding to a Borel subgroup.  Let $\alpha = e_n$, and let $\alpha^{\vee}$ be the coroot attached to $e_n$.  Then the standard Levi subgroup $M_{\operatorname{so}}$ of $\operatorname{SO}_{2n+1}$ corresponding to $\theta = \Delta - \alpha$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{GL}_n$.

Let $$p:\operatorname{Spin}_{2n+1} \rightarrow \operatorname{SO}_{2n+1}$$ be the simply connected double cover of the special orthogonal group.  Let $T_{\operatorname{spin}}$ be the inverse image of $p$, and identify $\alpha^{\vee}$ as a coroot of $T_{\operatorname{spin}}$.

Finally, let $$\operatorname{GSpin}_{2n+1} = (\operatorname{Spin}_{2n+1} \times \mathbb G_m)/\{(1,1), (\alpha^{\vee}(-1),-1)\}$$  This is a reductive group whose derived group is the spin group.  If we identify $\Delta$ as a set of simple roots of the maximal torus $\operatorname{Image}(T_{\operatorname{spin}} \times \mathbb G_m)$ of $\operatorname{GSpin}_{2n+1}$, it is known by looking at the root datum of $\operatorname{GSpin}_{2n+1}$ that the Levi subgroup $M$ corresponding to $\theta = \Delta - \alpha$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{GL}_n \times \operatorname{GL}_1$.

There are a couple of things I am trying to find out, and wanted to ask if the answers were known or could be found in the literature.

- 1 .  Supposing an isomorphism $M \cong \operatorname{GL}_n \times \operatorname{GL}_1$ is given, is there an explicit description of $M_{\operatorname{spin}} := M \cap \operatorname{Spin}_{2n+1}$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n \times \operatorname{GL}_1$?
- 2 .  Supposing also a matrix realization of $\operatorname{SO}_{2n+1}$ is realized, so that $M_{\operatorname{so}}$ is identified with $\operatorname{GL}_n$, is there an explicit description of the covering map

$$\operatorname{GL}_n \times \operatorname{GL}_1  \supset M_{\operatorname{spin}}\xrightarrow{p|_{M_{\operatorname{spin}}}} M_{\operatorname{so}} = \operatorname{GL}_n$$

Comment: Why does Spin embed into GSpin in this language?

Comment: Because $\operatorname{Spin} \times \{1\}$ has trivial intersection with the central subgroup $\{(1,1), (\alpha^{\vee}(-1),-1)\} \cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.